# Profile a Java Application Running on Google Dataflow

Tags: java, profiling, google-cloud-dataflow

Do you have any idea how to profile a java application running on a dataflow worker? 
Do you know any tools that can allow me to discover memory leaks of my application?

Answer (score 2):

For time profiling, you can try the instructions described in this [issue 72](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/issues/72), but there may be difficulties with workers being torn-down or auto-scaled away before you can get the profiles off the worker. Unfortunately it doesn't provide memory profiling so it won't help with memory leaks.

You can also run with the `DirectPipelineRunner`, which will execute the pipeline locally on your machine. This will allow you to profile the code in your pipeline without needing to deal with Dataflow workers. Depending on the scale of the pipeline you'll likely need to adjust the input size to be something that can be handled on one machine.

It may also be helpful to try to distinguish code that runs on the worker -- eg., the code within a single `DoFn` and the structure of the pipeline and the data. For instance, out-of-memory problems can be caused by having a `GroupByKey` with too many values associated with a single key and reading that into a list.